# Java Set Layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

I need to create a JFrame which has three JPanels laid out as shown:

[image]

Could anybody please tell me how I can achieve this layout? I have already tried using `BorderLayout`, but in `BorderLayout`, if I add the topmost pane at `BorderLayout.NORTH`, the one in the center at `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and the one at the bottom to `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, the topmost pane becomes too small (in height) and the pane in the center becomes too big (in height).

P.S. I have already made the 3 panes and set their preferred sizes properly.

Comment: You could use a `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use all sorts of things, compound layouts (using two `BorderLayout`s for example) or other layouts, it will depend on what you ultimately want to achieve.

For simplicity, I'd use a `GridBagLayout`, for example...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            add(new ABigPanel(), gbc);

            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(new ASmallPanel(), gbc);
            add(new ASmallerPanel(), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class ABigPanel extends JPanel {

        public ABigPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }

    }

    public class ASmallPanel extends JPanel {

        public ASmallPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 180);
        }

    }

    public class ASmallerPanel extends JPanel {

        public ASmallerPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 40);
        }

    }

}
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details